# Outputting svgs to bundle with RollupJS using @rollup/plugin-image in a LitElement project

Tags: typescript, svg, web-component, rollup, lit-element

I am using `@rollup/plugin-image` to help resolve svg imports in my LitElement project as recommended here: https://github.com/rollup/plugins. I also declared the '*.svg' module in custom.d.ts since I am using typescript.

The issue is I don't know how to include SVG files in rollup's bundle output, which means my browser can't import those files later on and I see 401 errors in the console. To temporarily fix this I am just using an inline SVG tag wherever I need to see display an SVG in the render() function of my custom LitElement components. Please help me understand what I am missing.

My current (simplified) rollup.config.js:

```
// other imports ... 
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image';
const extensions = ['.js', '.ts'];
const commonPlugins = [
  json(),
  commonJS(),
  resolve({ module: true, jsnext: true, extensions }),
  postcss(),
  terser({ keep_classnames: true, keep_fnames: true }),
  **image(),** 
];
const babelPlugins = [
   ...
];
const babelInclude = [
   ...
];
const es6Bundle = {
  input: ['src/bundle/index.es6.ts'],
  output: {
    dir: 'dist/bundle',
    entryFileNames: 'index.js',
    format: 'iife',
    sourcemap: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    babel({
      extensions,
      presets: [
        [
          '@babel/preset-env',
          {
            targets: '>25%',
          },
        ],
        '@babel/typescript',
      ],
      plugins: babelPlugins,
      include: babelInclude,
    }),
    ...commonPlugins, // where image() gets included
  ],
};

export default [es6Bundle];
```

My output dir looks like this:
`dist/bundle/wc/*bunch of web-component.js files*`
and inside of `dist/bundle` there's index.js and index.js.map.

I might be confusing different concepts here, and if so I apologize. This is my first time using rollup and litelement.

Answer (score 2):

> The issue is I don't know how to include SVG files in rollup's bundle output, which means my browser can't import those files later on and I see 401 errors in the console

The aim of `@rollup/plugin-image` is to let you *inline* images in the code instead of importing them at runtime, so the browser shouldn't even try to load them...

It's supposed to be used like this:

```js
import {html, LitElement, customElement} from 'lit-element';
import myImage from './image.svg';

@customElement('my-test')
export class MyTest extends LitElement {

  render() {
    return html`
      <img src="${myImage}">
      // Or like this, if the `dom` option
      // of the plugin is set to true:
      ${myImage}
    `;
  }

}
```

However, I wouldn't recommend inlining SVG as base64: unlike other image formats it's completely interoperable with HTML as it is, so why increasing its size? See [here](https://css-tricks.com/probably-dont-base64-svg/) for more info on this topic.

You may want to take a look at other plugins such as [`rollup-plugin-svg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-svg) that let you bundle SVG as markup.